# "Notice (8): Undefined variable" in View (migration from CakePHP 1.x to 2.x)

Tags: cakephp, migration, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I've migrated from CakePHP 1.3 to CakePHP 2.x, but in the news listing, I get this error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: newsSet [APP/View/newsSets/view.ctp, line 19]
```

My controller is:

```
class NewsSetsController extends AppController {

    public $name = 'newsSets';
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $uses = array('Client', 'Block', 'NewsSet', 'Curse', 'Gallery', "News");

    public function index() {
        $this->NewsSet->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('newsSets', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->flash(__('Invalid NewsSet', true), array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $newsset = $this->NewsSet->read(null, $id);
        $block = $this->NewsSet->Curse->Block->findById($newsset['Curse']['block_id']);
        $this->set('block', $block);
        $news =  $this->NewsSet->News->find("all", array('conditions' => array('News.news_set_id' => $id), 'order' => 'News.order ASC, News.created DESC' , 'recursive' => 1));
        $this->set('news', $news);
        $tree = $this->navTree($id, $newsset['NewsSet']['curse_id']);
        $this->set('tree', $tree);
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<p><i>Creat: <?php echo $newsSet['NewsSet']['created']; ?></i></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `$this->set('news', $news);` to `$this->set('newsSet', $news);`.

Answer (score 1):

You have sent `$news` to the view, by issuing

```
$news = $this->NewsSet->News->find("all", array('conditions' => array('News.news_set_id' => $id), 'order' => 'News.order ASC, News.created DESC' , 'recursive' => 1));  
$this->set('news', $news);
```

but are referencing `$newsSet`.

The following should work:

```
<p><i>Creat: <?php echo $news['News']['created']; ?></i></p>
```

If you have set the correct relationships between `News` and `NewsSet` (i.e. `belongsTo` or `hasOne`), the following should also work.

```
<p><i>Creat: <?php echo $news['NewsSet']['created']; ?></i></p>
```

Comment: Hi @InigoFlores, thanks. 
I have already made the change but it doesn't work:

Undefined index: NewsSet

Comment: I assume it's the second line that is failing. Please confirm that `News belongsTo NewsSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice (8): Undefined variable: newsSet [APP/View/newsSets/view.ctp, line 19]

the notice because, variable newSet ($newSet) none in your public function view in NewsSetsController,

you pass variable to view look this,

$this->set('news', $news);

should,

$this->set('newsSet', $news);